# Angular HTTP get request is not working in ngOnInit

Tags: angular, httpclient

I am trying to fetch the data from backend API on component load.

> API call in service file

```
  getFiles(): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient.get<any>('http://localhost:5000/api/file');
  }
```

Subscribing to that service in component inside `OnInit`

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.postDataService.getFiles().subscribe( data => {
      console.log('test', data);
    });
  }
```

Its giving below response (200). I am not getting any error

```
code: "EINVALIDSTATE"
message: "Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state"
```

If I call the same service on `(click)` it works fine.

```
 testClick(): void {
    this.postDataService.getFiles().subscribe( data => {
      console.log('test', data);
    });
  }
```

Is there any issue with calling service in `ngOnInit`. How can make it work?

> ---
>
> EDIT
>
> ---

After so much of troubleshooting I found that its giving error when I try to load the child routes directly. If I load home page and then click on link to navigate to any component then this api call works fine.

Comment: Did you try doing with `OnChages`?

Comment: @Rohith Yes I did. But No Luck

Comment: The request in `ngOnInit` is probably send when the server is in `SentClientRequest` state, while the request in `testClick` is send when server is in `LoggedIn` state. You have to wait for the server to be in `LoggedIn` state before sending the request. Is there a way for you to track the `loggedIn` state on the client side?

Comment: @fridoo After so much debugging I found that its giving error when I try to load the child routes directly. If I load home page and then click on link to navigate to this component then this call works fine

Comment: @fridoo Yes. I am not understanding exatly. If I put the same api call in `app.componet.ts` it works fine.

Comment: Are you using http interceptors? You first have no know where the `INVALIDSTATE` message comes from. It's either send by your server or by an http interceptor.

Answer (score 0):

BTW **Requests can only be made in the LoggedIn state, not the SentClientRequest state** it's not angular error. it's server side error

Please have a look on [tediousjs.github.io](https://tediousjs.github.io/tedious/frequently-encountered-problems.html#:%7E:text=%22Requests%20can%20only%20be%20made,result%20before%20making%20another%20request.)

Comment: yes I know. But It works with on click so the confusion